# Controlling inner figure margins in R

Tags: r, par

I must have changed something in my `par()` settings, but I cannot recall what. It looks like my inner figure margins must have changed somewhere. This is obvious whenever I add lines, using the `lines()`, `abline()`, or `points()` functions during plotting.

Below is an image to illustrate the problem:

[image]

The black solid line at y=0 represents an `abline(h=0)`. As you can see, the line just crosses the plotting region.

Any ideas on how to fix this? I have tried multiple things, but did not come to a solution for this problem just yet.

Comment: I'm guessing you should try `par(xpd=FALSE)` ... ?  Or open a new graphics device to reset ...

Comment: @BenBolker `par(xpd=FALSE)` did just the trick. Thank you!

Comment: You can post that as an answer if you like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to my problem was given by setting `par(xpd=FALSE)` .

Thanks to Ben Bolker.